# Loading Maps API with the jsapi loader is deprecated

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-api, deprecation-warning

Recently I see this message in the console logs:

> Loading Maps API with the jsapi loader is deprecated.

This is the code which causes it:

```
connected: function() {
    ...
},

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;
    google.load('maps', '3', {
        other_params: 'key=YOUR_API_KEY',
        callback : me.connected
    });
    ...
}
```

Loading it statically this is not really an option for me, because `callback=connected` will call back to `window.connected()` instead of `me.connected()`:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=connected"></script>
```

What is the alternative to `google.load()`, while calling back into the local scope? The documentation at [Loading the Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?#Loading_the_Maps_API) only offers static loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding this function in the global scope:

```
window.connected = function() {
    console.log("Maps API connected");
};
```

It shows that it is connected, long before the application even launched:

```
Maps API connected
Util.js:747 [V] the Application was launched.
```

So this probably is a non-issue. All I have to do is to call it `afterender`:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function() {
        appdata.items.panel.Maps.connected();
    }
},
```